# How to install boost library on CentOS 7.3 64bit?

Tags: c++, boost, centos7, yum

I need to build a C++ project which uses Boost library on CentOS. I tried this:

```
yum install boost-devel
```

But I get dependency errors and Boost is not installed:

```
--> Processing Dependency: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit) for package: libboost_regex1_59_0-1.59.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit) for package: libboost_regex1_59_0-1.59.0-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libicudata.so.42()(64bit) for package: libboost_regex1_59_0-1.59.0-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: libboost_log1_59_0-1.59.0-1.x86_64 (enetres)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: libboost_locale1_59_0-1.59.0-1.x86_64 (enetres)
           Requires: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: libboost_regex1_59_0-1.59.0-1.x86_64 (enetres)
           Requires: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: libboost_locale1_59_0-1.59.0-1.x86_64 (enetres)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: libboost_log1_59_0-1.59.0-1.x86_64 (enetres)
           Requires: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: libboost_graph1_59_0-1.59.0-1.x86_64 (enetres)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: libboost_regex1_59_0-1.59.0-1.x86_64 (enetres)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: libboost_graph1_59_0-1.59.0-1.x86_64 (enetres)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: libboost_locale1_59_0-1.59.0-1.x86_64 (enetres)
           Requires: libicuuc.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: libboost_regex1_59_0-1.59.0-1.x86_64 (enetres)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: libboost_log1_59_0-1.59.0-1.x86_64 (enetres)
           Requires: libicui18n.so.42()(64bit)
Error: Package: libboost_graph1_59_0-1.59.0-1.x86_64 (enetres)
           Requires: libicudata.so.42()(64bit)
```

Am I supposed to install these dependencies manually? Or what is wrong exactly and what should I do?

Comment: Try `sudo yum remove boost boost-devel boost-system boost-filesystem boost-thread` first, maybe there is some old installation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Usually on centos 7, I do

```
yum update
yum install epel-release
```

and then

```
yum install boost boost-thread boost-devel
```

So far, it's worked for me.
Maybe first two commands are what you need to do initially. You can ask if any problem occurs later.
Be aware that Boost 1.53.0 ist the current version on YUM. If you need a version above that, you'll need to build from source. See https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html for details.